# RabbitMQ C++ client for old Debian

Tags: c++, debian, rabbitmq, libtool, autoreconf

I have an old Debian (Lenny), on which I develop an application that should connect to **RabbitMQ**.
I downloaded the official C++ client rabbitmq-c-0.8.0 from https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/releases/tag/v0.8.0 , but unfortunately, I can't compile it on my old Debian:

```
wget https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/archive/v0.8.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf v0.8.0.tar.gz
autoreconf -i
```

Result:

```
autoreconf -i
/usr/share/aclocal/libmcrypt.m4:17: warning: underquoted definition of AM_PATH_LIBMCRYPT
/usr/share/aclocal/libmcrypt.m4:17:   run info '(automake)Extending aclocal'
/usr/share/aclocal/libmcrypt.m4:17:   or see http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Extending-aclocal
Makefile.am:6: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
Makefile.am:6:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'
Makefile.am:6:   to `configure.ac' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.
Makefile.am:6:   If `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' is in `configure.ac', make sure
Makefile.am:6:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
autoreconf2.50: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Version of automake I have (and I can't upgrade it): **1:1.10.1-3**

Version of libtool I have (and I can't upgrade it as well): **1.5.26-4+lenny1**

Does anyone know how to build the RabbitMQ client on the old OS I use?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the best solution was to move to ubuntu 14+